# I am a Python noob and I cannot get the correct output for a tutorial. Can you direct me to the syntax for my function call

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    sval = input('Enter a number: ')
    if sval == 'done':
        break
    try:
        ival = int(sval)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

def num1(values):
    num1 = None
    for num1 in values:
        if num1 is None or num1 > num1:
            num1 = value
        return num1

def num2(values):
    num2 = None
    for num2 in values:
        if num2 is None or num2 < num2:
            smallest = num2
        return num2

print('Maximum is', num1('values'))
print('Minimum is', num2('values'))
```

My output is supposed to be:

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 3
```

My output is:

```
Invalid input
Maximum is v
Minimum is v
```

Comment: Please explain what you tried so far in order to solve your problem and where exactly you need help.

Comment: `num1('values')` and `num2('values')` actually meant that you are giving the function the word `value` as your input

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have made the error in this code. I am defining a function and assigning the arguments. I think I must be wrong in my syntax.  I have re-watched videos on this and I didn't figure out the syntax fully.                                                    def num1(values):
    num1 = None
    for num1 in values:
        if num1 is None or num1 > num1:
            num1 = value
        return num1

Comment: Thank you to all who answered. Thank you prokillerinminecraft! So I get why I did it wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are trying for these :

```
the_array = []
while True:
    sval = input('Enter a number: ')
    if sval == 'done':
        break
    try:
        ival = int(sval)
        the_array.append(ival)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

def maximum(values):
    num1 = 0
    for i in values:
        if i >= num1:
            num1 = i
    return num1

def minimum(values):
    num2 = 500000000000000000000 //big number justfor reference to find the lowest
    for i in values:
        if i <= num2:
            num2 = i 
    return num2

print('Maximum is', maximum(the_array))
print('Minimum is', minimum(the_array))
```

But you may use `Built-in function` to make your program shorter and much more easier to read:

```
the_array = []
while True:
    sval = input('Enter a number: ')
    if sval == 'done':
        break
    try:
        ival = int(sval)
        the_array.append(ival)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    
print('Maximum number :', max(the_array))
print('Minimum number :', min(the_array))
```

I'm not the `one line` guy but this should get your work done
[This is list of Built In function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp)
Goodluck on your python journey